# WPF Bind different commands to button/menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

I would like to ask you for an advice.

The application that I am working on has a `docking control` and should support working with different "documents". Therefore there can be multiple `windows`(tabs) opened at the same time.

Each can host a different content. The "documents" that I referred to could be a text file,
an excel style sheet or the main control that this app is being developed for (a geographical data visualization).

I am using the `MVVM` pattern and MVVM Light library. Note: I have a third party control for the excel spreadsheets.

Now I have a `menu bar` and a `toolbar` where I have common `menuitems` (in `menubar`) / buttons (in `toolbar`) like 'save', 'cut', 'copy' etc...  When you switch between between the tabs, the 'save' button should call the appropriate save functionality.

The same goes for cut/copy/paste:

- When in a tab with text document - cut/copy/paste should operate with text (there are wpf built-in commands for this).
- When in the main control - It should work with the graphical elements (I will have to implement these)
- When in the spreadsheet - It should work with the enclosed third party commands for the spreadsheet control.

Furthermore, there can be a tab that has some text selected - thus the menuitem/button for cut/copy should be enabled when switched to this tab, while some other tab has no graphical elements selected  thus the menuitem/button for cut/copy should be disabled when switched to this tab.

With the save `command` I can imagine one possible way to do it, but still, I am not sure whether it is a good way to implement it: Have a `RelayCommand` in MainWindowViewModel

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveCommand == null)
        {
            _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.SaveFile());
        }
        return _saveCommand;
    }
}
```

and the `SaveFile()` method would call some other 'save method' on the `datacontext` of the `selected` tab (which would be a viewmodel for the according "document" type).

However I don't know how to do the enabling/disabling of the save button/menuitem and I am clueless about how to achieve the different cut/copy/paste functionality.

I apologize for the length of the question. Maybe I could have just asked:

"How do you bind different cut/copy/paste commands to the buttons depending on which part of application is selected/active?".

But I felt the added context of what I am trying to achieve would help answer the question.

Comment: I would make MainViewModel have hold a collection of the other viewmodels and add a property for current selected viewmodel. Then the save command simply forwards calls to the current selected viewmodels save command/method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the SaveFile() method would call some other 'save method' on the
>   datacontext of the selected tab (which would be a viewmodel for the
>   according "document" type).

The SaveFile should be implemented by the ViewModel without going back to the View.

Create several ViewModels to represent different kind of documents and let each implement its Save functionality.

The CanExecute method of a command can be used by the View to decide whether or not the menu item or button should be enabled. All you need is to implement the CanExecute method in the ViewModel. In most cases a Save command's CanExecute would use an IsDirty or similar property.

**EDIT**

For menu items that should be context/active tab item aware you could create a main ViewModel with the commands for the menu and a collection of ViewModels (one for each tab item)

In the command handlers of the context aware menu items get the active ViewModel and pass the command on.

To get the current TabItem, bind the SelectedItem to a property of the main ViewModel (the type of the property could be a base class of the ViewModels).

That way you do not need to get back to the View to get the current tab item.

Comment: When a datacontext of a view (selected tab) is a corresponding viewmodel (one type for each document type) then I don't understand where is the code going back to the view? What do you mean? In the viewmodel I need to somehow find out which tab is selected. The only way I was able to do that so far was to cycle through the collection (i hold a reference) and find the selected tab. But you are probably right, there should be another way to find out the currently selected view. Could you please also help me with the cut/copy part of the question? Then I could mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Please see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Just found out the control I am using (Telerik docking) does not support SelectedItem (or something like ActiveDocument in AvalonDock).
It has `object SelectedContent` or `RadPane SelectedPane` - I could do
    public Object SelectedPane {
        get {...}
        set
            {
            BaseViewModel var = (value as UserControl).DataContext as BaseViewModel;
            }
        }
but I don't know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know the telerik control so you might need to ask a specific question on that on either SO or on the Telerik forum. Anything that uses bindings can be replaced by code/eventhandling, it is just a lot more work.

Comment: I understood that it is not good to bind to a property that has a type of some view specific class, like
RadPane SelectedPane {}. I understood that I should bind to a property that has a type of viewmodel (or their baseclass).  So I was asking whether
binding to Object SelectedContent {} is a better solution (it returns the view as an object, but casting to UserControl gives us the datacontext which is the viewmodel). It is just not direct,
like having BaseViewModel ActiveTab {}.

Comment: Also i found out there is a SelectionChanged event on the control. So I thought could try to do this using eventhandlig as an excersise (or to create a property that returns viewmodel as an extension) 
- could you please give me a link that has an example? I would be really grateful.